# How to do "if-for" statement in python?

Tags: python

With python, I would like to run a test over an entire list, and, if all the statements are true for each item in the list, take a certain action.

Pseudo-code: If "test involving x" is true for every x in "list", then do "this".

It seems like there should be a simple way to do this.

What syntax should I use in python?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `all()`.  It takes an iterable as an argument and return `True` if all entries evaluate to `True`.  Example:

```
if all((3, True, "abc")):
    print "Yes!"
```

You will probably need some kind of generator expression, like

```
if all(x > 3 for x in lst):
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Using it to solve some project euler problems. Finding the 10001st prime is much easier with the all statement!

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> x = [True, False, True, False]
>>> all(x)
False
```

[all()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) returns `True` if all the elements in the list are `True`

Similarly, [any()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) will return `True` if *any* element is true.

Answer (score 4):

Example (test all elements are greater than 0)

```
if all(x > 0 for x in list_of_xs):
    do_something()
```

Above originally used a list comprehension (`if all([x > 0 for x in list_of_xs]):` ) which as pointed out by delnan (Thanks) a generator expression would be faster as the generator expression terminates at the first `False`, while this expression applies the comparison to all elements of the list.

However, be careful with generator expression like:

```
all(x > 0 for x in list_of_xs)
```

If you are using pylab (launch ipython as 'ipython -pylab'), the all function is replaced with numpy.all which doesn't process generator expressions properly.

```
all([x>0 for x in [3,-1,5]]) ## False
numpy.all([x>0 for x in [3,-1,5]]) ## False
all(x>0 for x in [3,-1,5]) ## False
numpy.all(x>0 for x in [3,-1,5]) ## True
```

Comment: That should be a generator expression!! Since generators calculate the values on-demand, (1) you don't waste any memory on a whole list and (2) you never computed the values after the first falsy, since `all` aborts there and doesn't consume the generator any further.

Answer (score 3):

```
if reduce(lambda x, y: x and involve(y), yourlist, True):
   certain_action()
```

`involve` is the action you want to involve for each element in the list, `yourlist` is your original list, `certain_action` is the action you want to perform if all the statements are true.

Comment: What is `invovle`?  Does this exist in Python?

Comment: @Sven just from the OP: "involve all", "certain_action".

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want the `all()` method:

```
$ python
>>> help(all)
Help on built-in function all in module __builtin__:

all(...)
    all(iterable) -> bool

    Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.
```

Answer (score 0):

`all()` alone doesn't work well if you need an extra `map()` phase.

see below:

```
all((x==0 for x in xrange(1000))
```

and:

```
all([x==0 for x in xrange(1000)])
```

the 2nd example will perform 1000 compare even the 2nd compare render the whole result false.